# Скрыть часть ссылки с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Как можно изменить ссылку:
    http://localhost/blog/read_more.php?article=3

На ссылку:
    http://localhost/blog/article=3

Т.е скрыть часть:
    read_more.php?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^blog/article=([0-9]+)$ /blog/read_more.php?article=$1 [L]
```

параметр `L` указывает, что следующие правила не будут работать, если сработает это.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе волшебник))): http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Пишеш реальный url потом, то что ты хочешь далее уже всё готово можешь переходить по ссылке которому ты хотел увидеть.

Comment: Только что я сам использовал `http://site.ru/page/2` выдает 500 ошибку apach нужно настроить а если сделать `http://site.ru/page-2` всё на ура